# What is the approximate lifespan of H125 helicopter

Tags: aircraft-performance, helicopter

What is the lifespan of the Airbus H125 helicopter used by law enforcement agencies?

Answer (score 4):

It's essentially impossible to know the "lifespan" (depending on what exactly you mean by that term) of the H125 helicopter.  Since, as the source below indicates, the longest H125 in service is 45 years, it's probably reasonable to conclude that its "lifespan" will be somewhat more than 45 years.

As a practical matter, the lifespan of any aircraft is based on, among other things, being properly maintained, the availability of parts, maintaining a competitive operating cost compared to similar aircraft, etc. Some aircraft have continued in useful service for many, many years.

---

---

An  Airbus H125 (**formerly an AS350**) has been in service at least **45 years** according to this [source](https://www.airbus.com/en/products-services/helicopters/civil-helicopters/h125/h125-technical-information).

[image]

[image]

([Image Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurocopter_AS350_%C3%89cureuil))

Comment: "the lifespan of any aircraft is based on, among other things, […] maintaining a competitive operating cost" – Yep. Typically, it is external factors that limit the lifespan. For example, in Germany, new noise pollution regulations forced operators of aircraft that operate in low-level flight in residential areas (in other words, law enforcement and emergency services helicopters) to change their helicopters (either upgrade them with hush kits where available or buy newer, quieter models), not any sort of mechanical issue.

Answer (score 1):

Classic lawyer answer: Well, it depends....

Airframes are typically rated on fatigue life for several thousand hours of flight time.  But that is the airframe only;  there are a lot of life limited parts eg rotor blades, which must be periodically replaced.  With a proper maintenance schedule observed, time in service can be extended quite a lot, possibly indefinitely.

Length of service would also depend upon a number of other factors, including, but not limited to:

- Total Time logged on the airframe annually.
- Exactly what type of flying the aircraft was subjected to ie an H125 will probably have a longer fleet life flying executive shuttle flights vs being used for logging, utilities work or flight instruction.
- Environment that the aircraft is operated and stored in (an aircraft which is always hangered after use and flown in a dry, arid place will fare much better than one operated in the tropics and parked out in the elements while not in use.).
- Care shown to the aircraft by crewmembers during use (are you leaving pens and other junk in the cockpit?).
- Discipline and attention to detail in a required maintenance schedule (have you been neglecting ADs, SBs or preventative maintenance?).

UPDATE:  As the OP has now noted that the intended use of the H125 is as a LE helicopter, it does narrow the conditions down a little bit more. Provided again that it received good care, and most LE agencies, maintain hangers and decent maintenance schedules on their aircraft, it should remain in service with the department, or be replaced by the department, well before its airworthiness, can no longer be maintained.

Comment: Fully agree, see my comment on the other answer providing an example for Germany, where law enforcement and emergency services helicopters had to be changed because of noise pollution regulation, not any restrictions on airworthiness.